# SQL Count Duplicates then Sum

Tags: sql, count, duplicates

I am trying to determine as a one number total of all duplicates in tables.
I have the below code - it counts the records and returns each row.

I just need to count the duplicates in 2 tables and show as one figure?

Thanks in advance.

```
(
select SUM(counts.cnt) as total
from
(
select COUNT(ID) as CNT
from table1
group by ADBOR_ID
having COUNT(ID) > 1
union
select COUNT(ID) as CNT
from table2
group by ID
having COUNT(id) > 1
                     ) COUNTS
)
```

Comment: Please provide the complete test case, with the exact database you are using, the `CREATE TABLE` statements, the `INSERT` statements to provide the input data, and the exact actual result you see, plus the exact expected result you wish to generate.  See the answer for the kind of SQL that would be helpful in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `UNION` is `UNION DISTINCT`, which removed any duplicate rows from the result.

[The fiddle (adjusted to also show the original result)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3cc1203007017d25cfe39d19e5fb2e9)

Try changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL`, like this...

The SQL (Q2):

```
SELECT SUM(counts.cnt) as total
  FROM (
         SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt
           FROM table1
          GROUP BY adbor_id
         HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
          UNION ALL
         SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt
           FROM table2
          GROUP BY id
         HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
       ) counts
```

The setup (with SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id int, adbor_id int );

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
    (1, 5)
  , (1, 6)
  , (1, 6)
  , (1, 6)
;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( id int );

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
    (5)
  , (6)
  , (6)
  , (7)
  , (7)
  , (8)
  , (8)
  , (9)
  , (9)
;
```

The prior SQL (Q1):

```
(
   select SUM(counts.cnt) as total
     from (
         select COUNT(id) as cnt
           from table1
          group by adbor_id
         having COUNT(id) > 1
          union
         select COUNT(id) as cnt
           from table2
          group by id
         having COUNT(id) > 1
        ) counts
)
```

The result (Q1):

| total |
| --- |
| 5 |

The corrected result (Q2):

| total |
| --- |
| 11 |

Comment: Thanks for this Forgot about the union.
When I run the 2 queries inside the select SUM separately I receive a total of 250 for Table 1 and 422 for table 2. However when I run the entire query it returns a total of  1366.

Comment: @Marc You need to show the complete test case in your question, with the exact SQL.  It's tough to guess what other issues you have.  If the answer was useful, please note it with an upvote.

Comment: @Marc When you have time, add those details to the question.  The SQL you showed in the question will never behave as you just described.  So you must be running something different.  The SUM of the two UNION'd results can never be more than the individual results, not in your original SQL.  Lots of assumptions here, since you didn't even show the schema.

Comment: @Marc The individual SUMs (of individual counts) can be more than the UNION'd SUM, as I've shown, due to the UNION (without ALL).  But not the other way around.